# Benefits of specifying my page encodings in UTF-8?

Tags: character-encoding

What are the benefits of changing all the page encodings from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1?

Comment: I'd guess that the answer is "none whatsoever", but since I can't back that up I won't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The W3C recommends UTF-8 because it is a recognizable encoding -- text that purports to be UTF-8 can be validated as such (with a very high probabality).

Also UTF-8 can encode all unicode code points losslessly.  This contrasts sharply with ISO-8859-1 (a.k.a. Latin-1) which can only encode code points below 256.

There are some trade-offs.  Latin-1 compactly represents most European texts at one byte per character.  And, Latin-1 is indexable (i.e. the fifth character is found at the fifth byte offset) while UTF-8 is variable length (requiring sequential access).

Answer (score 1):

None ! In ISO-8859-1 you will have less characters, and changing from UTF-8 to ISO will possibly break lot of things.

Comment: So I can change up (i.e. ISO => UTF-8), just not down.

Comment: If your website require extra characters (like é à, € , ...)  yes, but if your happy with the ISO characters, it's seems to me there is no need to change .